# Jekyll: How to place an Include within Markdownified Data?

Tags: include, markdown, jekyll

I'm trying to use Jekyll as a very modular CMS. I've got my `index.html` file, in which I include 'blocks' of code, like so:

`{% include blocks/info.html ref="info" %}`

This block defines the HTML structure, and the `ref="info"` references the data file that defines the content.

This is the block HTML structure:

```
{% for item in data[include.ref] %}
    <li id="jumpTo-{{ item.id }}" class="active">
        <h3 class="m-accordion-contentTitle">{{ item.heading }}</h3>
        {{ item.text | markdownify }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

And then I have my data file `info.yml`:

```
- heading: Setting
  id: setting
  img-pull: right
  text: |
    Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.

    {% include blocks/image.html %}

    Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.
```

Here my `text` is markdown, that the `markdownify` plugin takes care of converting into markdown. So my links turn into links, ems turn into ems. Everything is good. **Except** that my include doesn't work here. It works in a regular `markdown.md` file - the markdown will get converted properly but the include will also get rendered as HTML. But here the include is just rendered as plain text.

How can I get this include to render as HTML?